# Standardizing The Exporter Names and The Total Amount With Various Specific Code by Using Loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, while-loop

I have the variety of exporter name in data1 as input. Some of the exporter name have different spelling but represent the same company. Each company was classified in specific code. So, I need to arrange the data and create different data frame based on the code. The total amount for repeating company need to be sum up.

This is the input named data1:

```
structure(list(Exporter.Name = c("Comp A", "comp A", "Comp B", 
"Comp C", "Comp D", "Comp E"), code = c(8441, 8441, 8467, 8443, 
8467, 8441), Total.amount = c(100, 150, 200, 120, 180, 300)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I create the vector name "company_names" that will be used for the rename and the standardization of the company name, but do I need to repeat the same company name?

This is the code that I tried:

```
company_names <- c("Comp A", "Comp A", "Comp B", "Comp C", "Comp D", "Comp E")


# create new df for 8441
data8441 <- subset(data1, data1$`code` == 8441)

# rename & standardise the comp name
data8441$`Exporter.Name` <- ifelse(!(data8441$`Exporter.Name` %in% company_names), company_names, data8441$`Exporter.Name`)

# arrange the company name based on alphabetical order
data8441 <- data8441[order(data8441$`Exporter.Name`), ]

# Change the character to numerical data
data8441$`Total.amount` <- as.numeric(as.character(data8441$`Total.amount`))

# Sum by company 8441 and code
sum_comp8441 <- aggregate(`Total.amount` ~ `Exporter.Name` + code, data = data8441, sum)

# Print the resulting data frame
print(sum_comp8441)

# create new df for 8467
data8467 <- subset(data1, data1$`code` == 8467)

# rename & standardise the comp name
data8467$`Exporter.Name` <- ifelse(!(data8467$`Exporter.Name` %in% company_names), company_names, data8467$`Exporter.Name`)

# arrange the company name based on alphabetical order
data8467 <- data8467[order(data8467$`Exporter.Name`), ]

# Change the character to numerical data
data8467$`Total.amount` <- as.numeric(as.character(data8467$`Total.amount`))

# Sum by company 8467 and code
sum_comp8467 <- aggregate(`Total.amount` ~ `Exporter.Name` + code, data = data8467, sum)

print(sum_comp8467)

# create new df for 8443
data8443 <- subset(data1, data1$`code` == 8443)

# rename & standardise the comp name
data8443$`Exporter.Name` <- ifelse(!(data8443$`Exporter.Name` %in% company_names), company_names, data8443$`Exporter.Name`)

# arrange the company name based on alphabetical order
data8443 <- data8443[order(data8443$`Exporter.Name`), ]

# Change the character to numerical data
data8443$`Total.amount` <- as.numeric(as.character(data8443$`Total.amount`))

# Sum by company 8443 and code
sum_comp8443 <- aggregate(`Total.amount` ~ `Exporter.Name` + code, data = data8443, sum)

print(sum_comp8443)
```

[image: This is the output that I get and the expected output]

but if the vector "company names" was written like this:
`company_names <- c("Comp A", "Comp B", "Comp C", "Comp D", "Comp E")`

[image: The output was written like this]

Is there any other way or data type for me to write the company_names and how to make the coding in looping for different code?

Comment: use `aggregate(Total.amount~., data1, sum)`